# Find all functions that satisfy $\frac{f(x+y)+f(x)}{ky+f(x)}=\frac{kx+f(y)}{f(x+y)+f(y)}$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ for which there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$,$$\frac{f(x+y)+f(x)}{ky+f(x)}=\frac{kx+f(y)}{f(x+y)+f(y)}.$$
I already get the function when it is even by substituting $P(x,x) = f(2x)=kx$
but how to get when it is odd thank you

Comment: Hint: $ P ( x , 1 ) $ implies $ f ( x ) = \frac k 2 ( x + 1 ) + f ( 1 ) $ for odd $ x $ greater than $ 1 $.

Comment: i already found the solution already thank you

Comment: P(2x-1,1) then finish

Comment: Then it's a good idea to post a complete answer covering all the details, and accept it to close the thread.

Comment: I want to note that if by $ \mathbb N $ you mean the set of **positive** integers, i.e. a set not containing $ 0 $ in particular, then there is no solution to the functional equation, as one can conclude $ f ( 1 ) = 0 $ from it. If $ \mathbb N $ is meant to be the set of **nonnegative** integers, then there is a unique solution. I suppose you got all these, as you've "already found the solution"; but I found it worth mentioning.

Comment: natural number start from 1

Comment: i've done giving solution

Comment: "Find all functions" is a terrible title. See [how to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Comment: Two comments about "$ P ( x , y ) $": first, you haven't officially defined $ P $; adding something like "let $ P ( x , y ) $ denote the above functional equation" is necessary. Second, $ P ( x , y ) $ is not a number, and an expression of the form "$ P ( x , y ) = \dots $" is absurd. Some good alternatives would be "$ P ( x , y ) \equiv \dots $" and $ P ( x , y ) : \dots $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(x, y)$ denote the assertion in question

$P(x,x) = (f(2x)+f(x))^2 = (kx+f(x))^2$

since both of them are natural

$f(2x)+f(x) = kx+f(x)$

$f(2x)=kx$

for odd

$P(2x-1,1) = k(x-1)(-f(2x-1)+f(1)+k(x-1))=0$

since k positive and for all x  hence

$f(1)+k(x-1) = f(2x-1)$

$P(2x,1)= (f(2x+1)+f(1))(f(2x+1)+f(2x))=(2kx+f(1))(k+f(2x))$

$P(2x,1) = (2f(1)+kx)(2kx+f(1)) = (2kx+f(1))(k+kx)$
$P(2x,1) = 2k^2x+kf(1)=4kxf(1)+2f^2(1)$
giving us k = 2f(1)

therefore

$f(2x) = f(1)*2x $

$f(2x-1) = f(1)+2f(1)(x-1)=f(1)*f(2x-1)$

showing that f(x) is in the form of cx .QED $\square$

Comment: This answer is not yet complete, as I've previously mentioned in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404799/find-all-functions-that-satisfy-fracfxyfxkyfx-frackxfyfx?noredirect=1#comment9228196_4404799) under the question above. You haven't yet determined what values $ f ( 1 ) $ can possibly take. Check $ P ( 1 , 2 ) $, which shows that you must have $ f ( 1 ) = 0 $, which is impossible since $ 0 \notin \mathbb N $, and conclude that there is no solution.

Comment: Another side note: concluding $ f ( 1 ) + k ( x - 1 ) = f ( 2 x - 1 ) $ from $ k ( x - 1 ) \bigl ( f ( 1 ) + k ( x - 1 ) \bigr ) $ is only possible when $ x - 1 \ne 0 $. While $ f ( 1 ) + k ( x - 1 ) = f ( 2 x - 1 ) $ is true, it's not because "$ k $ [is] positive and [$ k ( x - 1 ) \bigl ( f ( 1 ) + k ( x - 1 ) \bigr ) $ holds] for all $ x $".

Comment: Correction of previous comments: you don't get $ f ( 1 ) = 0 $, but you get some relation between $ k $ and $ f ( 1 ) $, which poses a restriction on $ k $. You can then conclude that there exists a unique solution (for those $ k $ satisfying the required property). Sorry for my previously mistaken comments.

Comment: sorry does my solution finished already?  or there is some mistake I haven't check ,also pls delete the wrong comment so i could check it clearly

Comment: if im not wrong after i check again k is 2f(1)

Comment: Well done. There's one last step to complete the solution (if you're interested in getting ready for contests, note that you'll lose points if you don't mention this part). You've shown that  if a solution exists, then $ k $ must be even and we must have $ f ( x ) = \frac k 2 x $ for all $ x\in \mathbb N $. But you need to verify that this indeed gives a solution, i.e. you must put the obtained formula for $ f ( x ) $ back into the original functional equation and check that it holds for all $ x , y \in \mathbb N $. If it holds, you're done, and if it doesn't, no solutions exist.

Comment: I'll remove all my comments after you complete the solution. Now that everything looks fine, there's no purpose for them to be here.